# If a differentiable function approaches $-\infty$ as a limit from the positive side, must its derivative simultaneously approach $\infty$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

> Can we say that if $g: (0, \infty)\rightarrow\Bbb{R}$ is a differentiable function and $\lim \limits_{x \to 0+}g(x)= -\infty$, then  $\lim \limits_{x \to 0+}g'(x)= +\infty$ is always true?

I think the statement is true, I tried many functions, one of them is $-1/x$ for example, and I always get a true result. if its not true then I need a negative example, and if not, i really need some help to prove this formally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To give an explicit counterexample, let $g(x) = -\frac{1}{x(2+ \sin \frac{1}{x})}$. Then $g<0$ and $\lim_{x\to 0^+} g(x) = -\infty$. But

$$g'(x) = \frac{1}{x^2(2 + \sin \frac 1x)^2} (2+ \sin \frac 1x -\frac 1x\cos \frac 1x)$$

is negative when $x= \frac{1}{2n\pi}$ for all natural number $n$.

Comment: Man, this is impressive.

Comment: This is good, but now I feel like the question should be "given that the limit exists [...]"

Comment: @GPerez: If the limit of $g'$ exist then the assertion is true. Not sure if that is what the OP is asking for though.

Comment: @John I don't know either, just thought it worthy of note.

Comment: its given that first limit exists, and the example @john showed is suitable for the question.

Answer (score 1):

It is not true.  Here is one counterexample.  Intuitively, we start with $-1/x$ and add   small "bumps" to make the derivative not approach $\infty$ at $0$.  To get these bumps, define the function $b(x)=\exp(-1/(1-x^2))$ for $|x|<1$ and $0$ otherwise.  It can be shown that this is smooth.  Now, let $$g(x)=-\frac1x-\sum_{n>1} \frac{1}{n^2}b\left(\frac{x-1}{Nn}\right)$$ where $N$ is a fixed large number, chosen to make sure the supports of the bumps don't overlap.

Edit:  a simpler example is $g(x)=-1/x-sin(1/x)$.